# Is it worth iterating through a file twice to create a minimal data structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

This may be a simple question, but:

Say I have a file formatted so that there is one value on each line.
Say I wish to read through this file, and store each value in either an array or a vector.

The vector approach is simple. Read one line from the file, and insert into the vector.

The only way I can see using the array, is to loop through every line in the file once to count rows, then create an array of that size, and then loop through each line a second time to store the values.

Which is the better approach?
Is the extra bulkiness of a vector enough of a hindrance to be avoided? 
Is this irrelevant, and iterating twice through a file more of a hindrance?

Comment: There are other approaches, by the way, such as checking the file size and dividing by the average number of bytes in each line-value.

Comment: Standard containers in C++ (`vector`, `list`, etc) can change their size (in the sense of number of elements they contain) as required.     It helps if you know the size in advance (e.g. precomputing it) but not essential.   Generally speaking, running over a file twice won't make much difference for small files, but will be significantly worse than alternatives for large files.   Memory access is much faster than I/O device access,

Comment: There is no downside to the vector. It is not exactly "bulky". It's overhead compared with an array is perhaps a single pointer worth (8 bytes?).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `vector`, then each byte of data is written to RAM on average twice.

If you use the disk, then each byte is read on average twice, either from the disk or from the cache.

RAM being faster than disk, usually `vector` is the better approach.

The only way to tell anything for sure in performance analysis is to try both ways and measure. Science FTW.